VBA Code Adding Chart Data Label Works in Debug, not in Runtime
I'm creating a subprocedure to generate a gauge chart for a report. It's running fine until I get to the point of adding a data label to the "needle" of the chart. When I run it in debug mode, it works fine but once I try to run the full macro, the data label fails to come through. No errors occur in either scenario. The section of code is under "Needle label"

'Define worksheets
Dim source_data_sheet As Worksheet
Dim chart_destination_sheet As Worksheet

'Define chart
Dim gauge_chart As Object

'Define ranges
Dim gauge_name_range As Range
Dim gauge_value_range As Range
Dim needle_name_range As Range
Dim needle_value_range As Range
Dim needle_label_range As Range

Set source_data_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Data")
Set chart_destination_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

Set gauge_name_range = source_data_sheet.Range("A7")
Set gauge_value_range = source_data_sheet.Range("B8:B12")
Set needle_name_range = source_data_sheet.Range("A14")
Set needle_value_range = source_data_sheet.Range("B15:B17")
Set needle_label_range = source_data_sheet.Range("A15:A17")

left_val = 100
top_val = 100
width_val = 300
height_val = 300

Set gauge_chart = chart_destination_sheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut, left_val, top_val, width_val, height_val)

With gauge_chart.Chart
    .SetSourceData gauge_value_range
    
    'Format Chart Title
    With .ChartTitle
        .Text = "Labor Utilization"
        With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .Bold = msoTrue
            With .Fill
                With .ForeColor
                    .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                    .TintAndShade = -0.5
                    .Brightness = 0
                End With
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
        End With
    End With
    
    'Remove legend
    .Legend.Delete
    
    'Correct orientation
    .ChartGroups(1).FirstSliceAngle = 270
    
    With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
        'Add data series name
        .Name = gauge_name_range
        
        'Transparent section
        With .Points(5)
            With .Format
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            End With
        End With
        
        'Upper Section
        With .Points(4)
            With .Format
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                With .Fill
                    With .ForeColor
                        .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .Brightness = 0
                    End With
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            End With
        End With
        
        'Middle Section
        With .Points(3)
            With .Format
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                With .Fill
                    With .ForeColor
                        .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .Brightness = 0.4
                    End With
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            End With
        End With
        
        'Lower Section
        With .Points(2)
            With .Format
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                With .Fill
                    With .ForeColor
                        .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .Brightness = 0.8
                    End With
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            End With
        End With
        
    End With
    
    'Add needle
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    
    With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
        .Name = needle_name_range
        .Values = needle_value_range
        .XValues = needle_label_range
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .AxisGroup = 2
        
        'Transparent Section 1
        With .Points(3).Format
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
        
        'Transparent Section 2
        With .Points(1).Format
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
        
    End With
    
    'Reorient needle
    .ChartGroups(2).FirstSliceAngle = 270
    
    'Needle label
    With .FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(2)
        .ApplyDataLabels
        With .DataLabel
            .ShowCategoryName = True
            .ShowValue = False
            With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                .Bold = msoTrue
                With .Fill
                    With .ForeColor
                        .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                        .TintAndShade = -0.5
                        .Brightness = 0
                    End With
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

End With

gauge_chart.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
gauge_chart.Line.Visible = msoFalse

End Sub```


Maybe add a screen shot of the source data so we could test more easily?  Have you tried adding a few DoEvents in the relevant section, in case that helps.
